# Why do I get the error 'Value to add was out of range' with TDMSReader, NationalInstruments.Tdsm.File.Group.Channel?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
'Value to add was out of range. (Parameter 'value')'.
```

I am having troubles with ToList and IEnumerable using TDMSReader from Nuget. 
I have tried to loop through IEnumerable and add to new list, but the main error comes from the ForEach loop. I have also tried ToList, which gives the same error.

I cannot read the value that is throwing the error as it happens in the foreach loop before I get to next 'item'. From everything I've found, it is probably a DateTime min/max error, but I can't find an error in the data and have tried removing any dates between 2000 and 2021. I can get up to 2961 records in 'da' before an error is thrown. There are 6204 records in 'channel' though.

```
using LambdaTdms.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TdmsMaster.Managers
{
public class StackOverflow
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string basePath = Functions.GetBasePath();
        string filePath = Functions.GetNewFilePath(basePath);
        if (filePath == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (NationalInstruments.Tdms.File file = new NationalInstruments.Tdms.File(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                file.Open();
                List<PutObjectResponseModel> models = ByChannel(file);
                file.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error handling
            }
        }
    }

    private List<PutObjectResponseModel> ByChannel(NationalInstruments.Tdms.File file)
    {
        List<PutObjectResponseModel> responseModels = new List<PutObjectResponseModel>();
        foreach (var group in file.Groups)
        {
            foreach (NationalInstruments.Tdms.Channel channel in group.Value)
            {
                string fileName = $"{FormatPath(group.Key)}_{ FormatPath(channel.Name)}";
                IEnumerable<DateTime> datas = channel.GetData<DateTime>();
                //Error: datas.ToList();

                List<DateTime> da = new List<DateTime>();
                try
                {
                    datas = datas.OrderBy(c => c.Year)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Month)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Day)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Hour)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Minute)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Second)
                        .ThenBy(c => c.Millisecond);

                    datas = datas.Where(p => p.Year > 2000).Where(p => p.Year < 2021);

                    //Error: foreach (DateTime item in datas)
                    foreach (DateTime item in datas)
                    {
                        DateTime dt = (DateTime)item;
                        if (dt == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            da.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //handler error thrown from  *foreach (DateTime item in datas)
                }
            }
        }
        return responseModels;
    }

    private string FormatPath(string path)
    {
        path = path.Replace("/", " ").Replace("?", "").Replace("*", "");
        return path;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if your order by is causing issues, but I recommend

> > datas.OrderBy(c => c);

Comment: I recommend not to answer if you're not sure, just leave comment.

Comment: I recommend you respond with something useful to the question, Alex.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment :(